# Excel Structed Reference to filter Table and produce List

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter a table in excel and return a different column to create a list for data validation.

My table contains a list of names and one of the columns is a Yes or No for being an admin.

I want to create a data validation list on another sheet and use the filter table to just show those names that have a Yes in their associated row in the table.

I recorded a macro to filter the table to show just the rows I need and now want those names to appear in the list.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Staff").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
```

Is this possible?

I had tried using the =FILTER() formula but it's not available in my version of Excel.

I'd prefer to do it with a formula in the validation settings rather than VBA.

Comment: Don't think you can do it with autofilter. Maybe advanced filter where you can copy to another range and then reference that in your DV?

Comment: The more was looking into I thought maybe I could do it with a named range?  I can create a list for `=Staff[#All]` or `=Staff[Full Name]` for just that column.  But I want to be to able to filter the table by admin="yes" and return the `Staff[Full Name]` column

Comment: Your only options for a DV list are a literal comma delimited string, or a range. You cannot use just the visible cells in a filtered table unless you actually copy them somewhere else.

Comment: @Rory yeah I had thought as much but hoping to generate a named range somehow from the filtered table.

Comment: Nope. When I said "your only options" I meant "your **only** options".

Comment: @Rory touché   Thanks

Comment: :) If you can sort the table on the admin column, you could define a name to return just the contiguous block of Yes cells.

Comment: Thanks but don’t think that’ll be an option. Best solution do far is the one from @sjr

Answer (score 1):

This is something of a faff but I think it works, though by no means the best way of doing it.

Table of data on the left.

The "Yes" names are listed in D1 and down, the formula is an array (use Ctrl, Shift and Enter to confirm). I'm sure someone cleverer than me can shorten this.

```
=IF(ROWS(D$1:D1)<=COUNTIF(Table1[Admin],"Yes"),INDEX(Table1[Name],SMALL(IF(Table1[Admin]="Yes",ROW(Table1[Name])-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(D$1:D1)),1),"")
```

E1 is just the total of the names shown in D (another array formula):

```
=SUM(IF(LEN(D:D)>0,1,0))
```

The DV is in G1 and the formula there is

```
=OFFSET(D1,0,0,E1,1)
```

If you change e.g. Sarah to Yes, her name will appear in D and will be added to the DV list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks seems to work as described but obviously would prefer to implement it with helper cells.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've applied your filter to column 8, you can select the range that remains visible in a different column using:

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Staff").Range.Columns(8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, -2)`

This would return a range consisting of column 6 (8-2) of your table. Adjust to suit your needs.

You could then cycle through that range one cell at a time and populate a new range from it, accordingly.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it WITHOUT VBA, is it possible to do with just a formula?
For example even creating a named range `=Staff[#All]` but filtering that and returning on the name column?

Comment: Some kind of array formula *might* work I guess.. I'll have a play and come back if I find a way. I'm sure someone else will beat me to it though..